# A holographic matrix puzzle

Tags: progressive-matrix

Fill the missing square.
[image]

It is my own creation.  It is not part of a test, so there is no ABCD choice.  You must figure out the underlying rule to find the missing pattern.

Before you ask: nothing to do with noughts and crosses (aka tic-tac-toe).

Hint:

> The key is in the title.
>  Don't try to find a row rule or column rule.

Hint:

> All x's and all o's are not equal.  Maybe this can help.
>   [image]

Hint:

> It is marked as "progressive-matrix" because it is the closest.
>  But I don't think "progressive" is the correct term.  There is no pregression between the squares.
>  Also, instead of "holographic" I should better say "auto-holographic".
>  It should be called an auto-holographic matrix puzzle.

Hint:

> Here is an easier version of the problem.
>  [image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Just want to make sure. No need for the "knowledge"-tag?

Comment: No.  And I guess it is time for another hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> [image]

Explanation:
(squares and positions within squares will be referred to as 1-9 via dial pad convention)

> The final hint suggests that symbols exist in pairs, as each letter is usually used twice. I noticed in the final hint that on the top row, the `h` in square 3 was in position 1, and the `h` in square 1 was in position 3. This gave me the rule:
>
>  Symbols are placed in pairs; the position within a square of one symbol should point to the square of the other, and vice versa.
>
>  Checking all the pairs in the final hint, and later the original grid, this rule seems to bear out. There is one special case in square 6, where an `f` is in position 6--in this case, the symbol is its own compliment, and it does not exist as a pair.
>
>  Looking at the given eight squares, three have a symbol in position 9. This determines the first eight positions in square 9:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Given just the rule above, there is no way to determine whether the ninth position is empty or contains a self-complimenting symbol. However, looking at the other squares, each contains exactly three symbols. Following this pattern, the final position of the ninth square must be empty.

Aside:

> The solution to the easier version given in the last hint spells out `win`. :D

Comment: Correct.  And what makes it holographic?

Comment: @FlorianF Honestly, I'm not sure. I know a hologram involves light interference, or can refer to a projected 3d image, but I'm not sure how that relates to the solution

Comment: Maybe I am abusing the term.  In a hologram every part of a hologram contains the image of the whole object.  Here each part is reflected in the whole.